# Recharts - labels display numbers as %

Tags: reactjs, label, recharts

Using the example barchart on the recharts site, I'd like to display the number on the label as a %. https://jsfiddle.net/gearoid/7e717fa8/1/

```
const data = [
    { name: "18-24", audience: 35.18 },
    { name: "25-34", audience: 21.96 },
    { name: "35-44", audience: 7.26 },
    { name: "45-54", audience: 2.19 },
    { name: "55-64", audience: 0.67 },
    { name: "65+", audience: 0.33 },
    { name: "unknown", audience: 32.41 }
```

];

When I try adding the % to the array it's displayed in the label but it doesn't display the bar.
const data = [
        { name: "18-24", audience: 35.18 + "%" }
];`

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add [unit](http://recharts.org/en-US/api/Bar#unit) props in `Bar` component:

```
<Bar dataKey="audience" fill="#82ca9d" unit="%" />
```

Here's a [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7e717fa8/3/)

Comment: This does not work anymore

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Bhojendra Rauniyar did not work for me, but this worked:

```
const labelFormatter = (value) => {
    return value + '%';
};
...
...
...
<Bar label={{ position: 'right', formatter: labelFormatter }}/>
```

Comment: Worked for me on this day

Comment: using the property `tickFormatter` is now the recommended way. see [here](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/YAxis#tickFormatter).